# Rails & Devise: Firing an event on a new session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to track user sessions in my Rails app. In my Devise Sessions controller, I can track when a session is created... But that only tracks when a user specifically submits the login form. And I'm wanting to track the number of times a user returns to the app (most of the time, they won't need to resubmit the login form).

Where can I put my tracking code to achieve this?

Here's my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    super do
      mixpanel.track("Sign In")
    end
  end

  def destroy
    super do
      mixpanel.track("Sign Out")
    end
  end


  def new
    super
  end

end
```

To clarify:

1. user@gmail.com visits myapp.com and logs in to the webapp using password/email login (hits sessions#create)
2. The next day the user returns to myapp.com and does not need to manually login because the app has kept them logged in

The above should register as 2 "sessions" for this user so I am trying to figure out where I can fire the events.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'user returns to the app'? How is that happening without login?

Comment: yeah little more clarification please..

Comment: Tried to clarify @ArupRakshit

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand very well what you want but I will try.

In `config/routes.rb` you have different routes. You should find `root to: 'home#index'` or something like that. In this case, you can add the tracking code in `HomeController#index`. When the user loads the web app, it will open this endpoint, so you can track the event there.

Comment: But if OP only wants to track when user returns to app, this implementation will result in false hits every time the user opens this page during the session, not necessarily only when returning.

Comment: It is better to hold off your answer unless it is really clear. Otherwise it creates confusions to readers.. :)

Comment: I tried to clarify in OP. Here's the app: www.trailerpuppy.com.  I want to track how often specific users are visiting the app

Comment: Problem with adding the tracking code in HomeController#index is that if during the same "session", a user returns to the index multiple times, it will fire each time. What I'm really trying to see is how often a user is returning to the app

Answer (score 0):

In `application_controller.rb`, make a custom `before_action`, like the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :check_visit

  private
  def check_visit
    if current_user.nil?
      # You've got a visit that wasn't logged in
    else
      # You've got a visit that was logged in
    end
  end
end
```

We can't just put it in `home#index` or whatever your `root` is, since the might have a different page bookmarked (for example).

Comment: What if a user visits myapp.com.. Then clicks on settings page, then back to myapp.com.. Will this only run check_visit once?

Comment: Do you mean with the Back button in the browser?

Comment: Let's say they're just clicking around on different nav links. I'd only want to register it as one session.

Comment: Whenever `current_user.nil?`, a user is not logged into your app and you can do whatever (like increment the tracking count) accordingly.

Comment: Basically I want to track any time a logged in user returns to the site. For example, A user might visit facebook 5 times each day.  But I wouldn't want to count each profile/page/post that user views as a "visit". Only counting when they "leave" and then "come back". But I'm having trouble doing this when the user is already logged in when they return.